# Creates string parser to parse nested structures

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for information how to create parser to parse a strings like this:

`[1,2,"abc",[2.2345,76,"n"],["abc",1,"c"],23,44]`

Every value (number, decimal, string, null) in square brackets separated by comma and in brackets can be nested another square brackets with any number of values.

I need to create it in Java.

**Q:** Is there some library, algorithm / design strategy / design pattern, how to create such parser?

---

Edit:

```
final String value = "[1,2,\"abc\",[2.2345,76,\"n\"],[\"abc\",1,\"c\"],23,44]";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object[] foo = objectMapper.readValue(value, Object[].class);

List<Object> tokens = Arrays.asList(foo);
```

It works with single values (not nested arrays), is there a way how to parse these nested arrays directly in the first call or do I have to find these arrays in the `tokens` List and parse it separately?

Comment: That string can be parser with a JSON parser, so why try creating your own?

Comment: This is not a JSON format, is it? What library can I use?

Comment: What does the output of your imaginary parser look like?  How would the String in your question be parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested JSON Arrays are parsed into `List` objects. Since you seem to want the outer JSON Array as a `List` too, parse it into that, not into an `Object[]`.

You can see what you actually get with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String value = "[1,2,\"abc\",[2.2345,76,\"n\"],[\"abc\",1,\"c\"],23,44]";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<?> tokens = objectMapper.readValue(value, List.class);

    printTypes("", tokens);
}
static void printTypes(String indent, List<?> tokens) {
    for (Object token : tokens) {
        System.out.println(indent + token.getClass().getName() + " - " + token);
        if (token instanceof List)
            printTypes(indent + "  ", (List<?>) token);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
java.lang.Integer - 1
java.lang.Integer - 2
java.lang.String - abc
java.util.ArrayList - [2.2345, 76, n]
  java.lang.Double - 2.2345
  java.lang.Integer - 76
  java.lang.String - n
java.util.ArrayList - [abc, 1, c]
  java.lang.String - abc
  java.lang.Integer - 1
  java.lang.String - c
java.lang.Integer - 23
java.lang.Integer - 44
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to check out following [java library for JSON parsing](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) as the string you presented looks like JSON Array. In fact, you can check out [this](https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark) JSON parsers benchmark project - with this you can choose suitable json parser by yourself.

Comment: Thank you, but Im not sure my string is in JSON format.

Comment: I'm sure that the string you provided in the question is in JSON format.

Comment: Well then, I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson` library, I'll try it, thanks :-)

Comment: Added one comment to my original question, thank you.